# How to setup/configure laravel project on cloud server

Tags: html, apache, laravel, web, server

I have this laravel application on `/var/www/html/application-folder/public_html`

When I enter the `apache server IP` it doesn't load the laravel application instead it displays the Apache home page

How can I display the url `/var/www/html/application-folder/public_html` ?

When I type the full url I get the following error:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /folder/public_html/index.php on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server

Comment: Are you on a development machine or on shared hosting external server?

Comment: im on a full cloud linux machine with root access cent os 6.5  its the live installation I think is because the apache has to be configured from scratch

Comment: You may need to setup virtual host in your apache with `DocumentRoot` pointing to the `public` folder of your project. I have written about how to upload Laravel project on a shared hosting at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2410/deployment/7970/laravel-5-app-on-shared-hosting-on-linux-server#t=201612120605569448798.

Comment: to install a site built with laravel you have to install laravel via composer or just put the public_html of the finished laravel project as a normal php simple site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have full root access to your server then you can

**Step 1**
upload your laravel project from the development machine(local) to the `/var/www` on your server - upload all folders except `vendor` and `node_modules`

**Step2**
once the project is uploaded, run `composer install`, if you need any of the node packages run `npm install`

**Step 3**
create virtual host for your site with `DocumentRoot  /var/www/yourProjectFolder/public`

**Step 4**
Ensure `storage` folder has write permissions for your apache/webserver user - **recursively**

**Step 5**
Ensure that `public` folder has appropriate permissions - **recursively**, if you have uploaded the project as `root` then you will need to change the owner/permissions

Following this workflow you will be able to get your Laravel site up and running.

Important distinction to make here is that you have full root access to your server and that you can install composer and/or npm on your server before proceeding with the workflow.

If you can't install composer and/or npm on your server, then you have to upload the `vendor` directory to your server as well (and if you need any node packages then the `node_modules` as well) - following the documentation link in my comment above will help you.

Refer [Virtual Host on Cent Os 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6)

Comment: so basically only the public_html folder should be used and composer install ?

because really I was installing laravel then put a new larravel project then put the public_html inside this project like laravel new blog and put the public_html inside the blog folder

Comment: Why do you want `public_html` folder? If you install a new laravel project on your local development machine with laravel installer `laravel new blog` and then development your `blog` on your development machine, when its ready for production just upload the contents of `blog` folder except `vendor` and `node_modules` on your server at `/var/www/blog` then run `composer install` and setup virtual host and that is it.

Comment: Thats it thanks very much 
a lot of the answers when you search install laravel site make looks like you have to make a composer install laravel instead of just installing the folder Thanks

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If you need any further help get in touch (donkarnash@thinkstudeo.io). If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted answer for others to know. Good luck!

Comment: another thing related to laravel install, is there a difference between putting the folder on public_html being better or worse than on www ? or for example should be put in www and just the index.php in public_html ?

Comment: Generally for a linux based vps with apache2 webserver `/var/www` is the folder where all sites/projects reside for eg `blog` - a blogging project, `shop` - may be a store front etc, The file permissions are setup such that only the folders containing the code for web page display are publicly accessible - `public` folder for any laravel project, while the rest are set with restricted access. This ensures the core project(s) logic/code is secure. For a laravel project there doesn't arise a need to move the files as such - use file permissions to secure/ give access.