# how to upload a laravel project in free server

Tags: web, laravel-5, web-hosting

I need upload My Laravel project with free web server like https://www.000webhost.com/ this is My first time. I need some tutorials. I do not have database in the movement. can you help me?

Comment: My friend it's pretty difficult task. Anyway check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.3 and match the requirements based on laravel documentation. If hosting provider provides these extension then i am pretty sure you can install it via ftp or ssh. But again by ftp it is diffucult task. You have to check whether server provides ssh access.

Comment: To upload laravel project to a shared hosting you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2410/deployment/7970/laravel-5-app-on-shared-hosting-on-linux-server#t=20161222050035960594

Comment: And if you have vps, you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084164/url-to-application-on-apache